# Always display Tooltip in CanvasJS, regardless of mousehover

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I am currently working on a user input customizable pie chart web app through Javascript as a small side project, and currently stuck on trying to keep tooltips enabled.

Currently:

```
width: 800,
height:800,

tooltipContent: display,

animationEnabled: true,


title: {
  text: "ss"
},

legend: {
  maxWidth: 800,
  itemWidth: 800
},
```

doesn't seem to be cutting it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it by setting external toolTip on [mouseover](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/mouseover/) of dataSeries.

please check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/g02fvejz/)

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
<div id ="tooltip" style= "width: 7%; padding: 5px; border: 2px solid rgb(82, 81, 78); background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); border-radius: 5px; user-select: none;">No data</div>
<script>
   var toolTip  = document.getElementById("tooltip");
   function onMouseover(e){
       toolTip.innerHTML =  e.dataPoint.x + " : " + e.dataPoint.y ;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer Sanjoy!